# How to get boxplot stats from a dataframe with boxplot_stats?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is the data:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.cbook import boxplot_stats 

data = {'brand': {196: 'volkswagen', 247: 'seat', 280: 'renault', 307: 'volkswagen', 425: 'opel'},
        'price': {196: 137750.0, 247: 66900.0, 280: 63750.0, 307: 132500.0, 425: 78000.0}}

bdf = pd.DataFrame(data)

# get boxplot stats
boxplot_stats(bdf.brand.head(5))
```

And I successfully create a boxplot out of it.

However, when I try to get box plot stats I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: `boxplot_stats(bdf.price.head(5))`Isn't it the price column that gets the value of the boxplot?

Answer (score 0):

It should be probably `boxplot_stats(bdf['price'])` as the first parameter is data that will be represented in the boxplots.